# a database to store a non stationary distribution

Tags: nosql, redis, distribution

I have many categorical distributions. A categorical distribution is where one describes the probability of an event drawn from a set of k events. I need to be able to access the probability of an event very quickly.

One way to store a categorical distribution is in Redis using a sorted set. Each key indexes a separate distribution, each member of the sorted set is a specific event and each score is the number of times you've seen that event. For each key(distribution) you would also store the sum of counts for each event in that distribution, so you can normalise properly.

The question I'd like to ask is: what is a good way to store this data if the probabilities are changing over time? I'd essentially like to be able to forget old observations - i.e. to decrement the score and normalisation constant for each key at some regular interval.

With the redis approach above, I could run a cron job every d minutes, iterate over each distribution and decrement each count in the zscore and the normalisation constant. However, this seems bit wrong (I'm sure my mum told me to never iterate over KEYS *), and so I'm wondering if anyone else has solved this problem a bit more comprehensively?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what feels wrong to you is some combination of:

1. The need to visit every distribution, every member of each ZSET, and the normalisation constant whenever the cron job runs
2. The way that the unconditional decrement operation will, over time, skew distributions in favor of events that happen multiple times per cron cycle

I haven't done anything like this before, but one solution comes to mind if you're able to spare more storage.

The idea is to store, at a regular interval, a timestamped queue of snapshots.  Each snapshot represents the event counts in your distributions for that interval of time.  When you want to expire the old probabilities in your distribution, you pop the expired snapshots off the list and decrement the ZSETs accordingly.

More concretely, you'll need to:

1. Keep track in memory of the events that occur during the interval [*t<sub>k</sub> - t<sub>k-1</sub>*) and how many times each occurred -- a set of (event, count) pairs.  This is in addition to the (presumably) real-time updating of the ZSET scores and normalisation factors that you currently do.
2. At each tick *t<sub>k</sub>*, store the snapshot:

   1. Create a unique key *S<sub>k</sub>* to represent the snapshot at *t<sub>k</sub>* -- like a UUID or similar
   2. For each event *E* in the snapshot, create a unique hash key *q(E)*.  Choose a key encoding that will allow you to recover the distribution (ZSET) key and event (member) key for that event.
   3. Call `HSET` *S<sub>k</sub>* with the event key *q(E)* and event count `|`*E*`|` to store the event data.  Repeat for all events in the snapshot.
   4. `RPUSH SNAPSHOTS <timestamp>:`*S<sub>k</sub>*
3. At each expiry tick *t<sub>m</sub>*, expire old snapshots:

   1. `LPOP` the SNAPSHOTS list, decoding the timestamp and verifying whether expired.
   2. If not expired, `LPUSH` it back onto the SNAPSHOTS list and you're done until the next expiry tick.  Otherwise...
   3. Decode the snapshot key *S<sub>k</sub>*
   4. Using the results of `HKEYS` *S<sub>k</sub>*, decode each event key *q(E)*, get the corresponding count, and then decrement the appropriate ZSET and normalisation factor by that amount.
   5. Repeat while expired snapshots still exist in the SNAPSHOTS list.

The amount of extra storage required will depend on the length of the snapshot and expiry intervals and the number of distinct events that occur within each snapshot interval.

In the worst case, every distribution and event will be represented in each snapshot, so this will not help with wrongness factor #1.  Optimistically, a suitably small percentage of distributions and/or events will be represented in any snapshot, and the efficiency of the expiration process will improve.  But this will address wrongness factor #2 even in the worst case, since events that happened recently will not be unconditionally decremented in your distributions each time the expiration cron job runs.